# Safe & Convenient method to hydrate CaO into Ca(OH)2?

Tags: safety

I'd like to prepare a solution of $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ from $\ce{CaO}$.

Ideally I guess I'd go for slowly adding the powder to a water-cooled round flask containing pure water but I have no mechanism to control the slow release of powder nor am I sure that the reaction wouldn't be fast enough to send the powder right back out of the flask.

Is the reaction slow enough for it to be safe and convenient to set pure water to slowly drip into the flask containing the powder (bathing in a large volume of water to dissipate the heat)? This would allow me to have my hands & mind free and control the flow to allow the heat to  slowly dissipate at the desired rate, if necessary I could change the water in the cooling bath once it reaches a certain temperature. This solution would appear more convenient though I have some concerns (if the reaction it too fast steam would pop $\ce{CaO}$ around in the flask, creating some airborne $\ce{CaO}$ coming out of it, I could do a closed system to work that around but if steam is produced I feel an open system would be safer). I'll wear protective equipment to set up everything, though I'd still rather not take unnecessary risks.

In the worse case I could hydrate a portion of $\ce{CaO}$ with steam in a cooled down space but that setup might be unnecessary.

Also, how can I calculate the amount of energy that will be released per quantity or weight from $\ce{CaO}$? (to know how much energy I'll need to dissipate)

Comment: I think you are worrying more than you should: CaO is not aggressive enough to keep you from experimenting a bit. Of course the concentration of the solution makes the difference, speaking of release of heat, but my suggestion is trying the operation on a small scale (with about 0.5 g of CaO and water scaled accordingly, for instance) to see how fast your mixing can be without releasing too much heat. If you find that heat is not a concern, or that it can be tamed by adding the base slowly, then you scale up

Comment: Remember that builders are ( or at least were ) used to perform this reaction in the scale of tens of kilograms of $\ce{CaO}$. General level of precaution for a lab scale is more than enough.